# Unit testing code that uses a Singleton

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have code that uses a Singleton (this happens to be for a website, so the Singleton has the scope of just that one Request; each Request will have their own singleton).

My code (which happens to be in an HttpModule) does the following:

1 - Checks if the Singleton object is null and, if so, initializes it.
2 - Updates a property on this singleton object along the lines of:

```
if(A)
{
    SingletonHolder.Current.X = Y;
}
else
{
    SingletonHolder.Current.X = Z;
}
```

I then want to have some unit tests around this method to check that logic is correct.  Let's say for argument's sake that we want the following 4 tests:

1. GivenMethodCall_When**A**_ThenXSetTo**Y**
2. GivenMethodCall_When**A**_ThenX**Not**SetTo**Z**
3. GivenMethodCall_When**NotA**_ThenXSetTo**Z**
4. GivenMethodCall_When**NotA**_ThenX**Not**SetTo**Y**

These tests all work perfectly when run one-at-a-time, but when run in VS2013 with the NUnit test runner then we get some failures because each test is run in parallel and the method under test is updating the same singleton object's property with different values.

Any advice on a pattern that would solve this?

Thanks

Griff

Comment: A pattern of making your class properly concurrent.

An even better pattern of not using a singleton.

In any case that's why you have tests

Comment: Is it an option to get rid of the singleton? That would be the best thing.  Create it at the start of the request and pass it into the methods that need it.

Comment: This important detail is not clear to me: If the singleton is unique per request, why isn't it unique per test call?  What's the difference here?

Comment: It depends on how the tests are stuctured. In any event, I'm assuing the OP is testing independently of ASP.Net itself, and therefore, the tests are not running in the context of a HTTP request. Therefore, without explicitly setting up and tearing down the Singleton object at the beginning and end of each test method, this would be the expected behavior (unless you're using xUnit ;) ).

Comment: The code under test is an EventHandler for the HttpApplication's BeginRequest event.  In this method, we create a singleton "Context" class that holds everything that the code in our web pages could possibly need (so info on the Site, the Customer, the Cache, the Tracer etc).  And Daniel, I apologize, I was wrong, the Singleton is of course available for everything in the AppDomain - I confused myself with the Items Collection on the HttpApplication (which is per request).  Maybe I need to have each test run in different AppDomains (or is that overkill?).

Comment: Based on my above comment, the following StackOverflow article discusses AppDomains.  Any thoughts on this as a pattern?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335174/unit-testing-c-net-classes-which-make-use-of-static-variables-unit-test-proce

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to provide a method within your test fixture decorated with the `SetUpAttribute` method to perform initial setup *before* each test method is run and another method decorated with the `TearDownAttribute` that runs *after* each test method. The documentation for the nUnit `SetUpAttribute` is found [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.5.10).

This will allow you to (in your SetUp method) initialize your Singleton object, and then (in your TearDown method) to set your Singleton object to `null` so that SetUp can re-instantiate/initialize the object for the next test.

Comment: Not sure how this would help.  If all tests run in parallel, then the Setups for each would run together, each trying to set up the same singleton.  The individual tests would all run together and update this singleton, causing some test's Asserts to fail, then each test's TearDown would then run.

Comment: Well then the fundamental flaw here is running the tests in parallel when you have global static data that is under test. Run the tests serially and use the SetUp/TearDown methods and this problem should go away.

Comment: We use the NUnit test adapter in VS2013 to run our tests and it automatically runs them in parallel.  We currently have thousands of tests on our application and they all complete within a matter of minutes.  I can envisage hundreds of tests on this area, so I think I'd prefer to have these run in parallel if at all possible.  I put a comment on the post above regarding running the tests in different AppDomains (including a link to a StackOverflow suggesting this).  I'm thinking this might be the way to go.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I don't see how a different AppDomain is going to matter. If the tests within the AppDomain run in parallel, you'll still have the same problem. Otherwise, you'd need one AppDomain per unit test method--and that would be fairly expensive I would think. There is an option you can pass to the test runner to disable parallel execution of unit tests--if it's feasible for you. If not, then I suspect you'll have to do as others said and try something other than a Singleton object.

Comment: @DrGriff:  Neither NUnit 2.6 nor the NUnitAdapter to Visual Studio runs  tests in parallell.  They are run sequentially. If you use Pnunit it will run in parallell, or the new 3.0 version.  So there must be something else causing the issue.

Comment: @TerjeSandstrøm Yeah, that's what I thought. But since I don't normally use NUnit, I was unsure of this fact. Thanks for the additional info. Based on that info, then what I suggested above ought to work fine for testing Singleton objects using NUnit.

Comment: Regarding parallel tests, not sure if the following applies to NUnit test adapter:   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx.  Even if these tests don't currently run in parallel, it sounds as though they may do one day when we get 3.0.  I think therefore segregating these tests into different AppDomains is maybe the safest way to go.

Comment: @DrGriff:  That applies to the MSTest runner. I can be invoked through the VSTest-runner, but if you set it to run tests in parallell it will revert to using the MSTest runner, and then it will NOT run NUnit nor XUnit. Even with the 3.0 a change in VSTest is required to run it in parallell.  I will try to contact them about the status of that.